# MOC3043 on Multisim

Tags: switches, ac, relay, triac, multisim

I've been looking to simulate an optocoupler-triac driver for an AC Load in Multisim but I can't find a working model for a light emitting optocoupler specifically(the MOC-30XX family). I would really appreciate if someone could guide me where to find a working model or how to create one. Thank you in advance.

Comment: The place I'd look is at the LTspice group on IO. You can sign up there and get access to their files. Look in their Files/z_yahoo/Lib/Opto/MOC302x OPTO TRIAC folder. It's got what you need, I think.

Comment: I could post up the files for you, though. Which do you prefer?

Comment: Thanks @jonk, can you post the MOC3021 please?

Comment: Did you get a chance to try out the model below? I hope it helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This model is taken from an LTspice yahoo group (that has since moved to a .IO site.)

```
* OPTO TRIAC
* Helmut Sennewald  8/10/2004
* MOC3021  I_trig=8mA
*  D+  D-  MT2  MT1
.SUBCKT MOC3021 1 2 3 4
.PARAM Itrig=8m
.PARAM RH1=20k
.PARAM RH2=20k
.PARAM RH3=16.7k
Q2 vb1 vb1p vd1 0 PNP1 off
Q1 vb1p vb1 4 0 NPN1 off
R3 vb1 4 {RH2}
D1 1 2 DL
R1 ctrl1 4 1
C1 ctrl1 4 10µ
R2 ctrl1 vb1 {RH1}
R4 vd1 vb1p {RH3}
B1 ctrl1 4 I=-500*I(D1)*3m/Itrig 
R6 vd2 vb2 {RH2}
D3 vd2 3 D1
Q3 vb2 vb2p 4 0 PNP1 off
Q4 vb2p vb2 vd2 0 NPN1 off
E1 vd2 N001 ctrl1 4 -1
R5 N001 vb2 {RH1}
R7 vb2p 4 {RH3}
D2 3 vd1 D1
R34 3 4 10000MEG
C34 3 4 30p
.MODEL PNP1 PNP(Is=1e-15 BF=10 Cjc=10p Cje=20p Tf=0.1u Ise=1e-12)
.MODEL NPN1 NPN(Is=1e-15 BF=10 Cjc=10p Cje=20p Tf=0.1u Ise=1e-12)
.MODEL D1 D(Is=0.1u Rs=2 Cj0=50p)
.MODEL DL D(Is=1e-20 Rs=5)
.ENDS
```

This is to be used with an "X" card in a Spice program. I don't know how that is handled in your Spice program. But all Spice programs support it in some fashion. The above model should work okay.